# controllerAs not working with inner directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In below code, controllerAs not working with widget and filter directive.

Can you please help me to fix this.
I couldn't figure out where exactly I'm doing wrong. :-(

**Expected output:**

Widget directive should print the "From widget controller".

Filter directive should print the "From filter directive".

I reproduced the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12208/), please check.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <body-dir>
    <icon-dir>
      <filter-dir>

      </filter-dir>
    </icon-dir>

    <widget-dir>

    </widget-dir>
  </body-dir>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('filterController', function filterController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test = "From filter directive";
  alert("filter");
  return vm;
});
myApp.controller('widgetController', ['$scope', function widgetController($scope) {
  var oki = this;
  oki.widget = "From widget controller";
  alert("widget");
  return oki;
}])
myApp.directive('bodyDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope) {
      alert('body-dir');
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('widgetDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'widgetController',
    controllerAs: 'oki',
    template: "<span>{{oki.widget}}</span>",
    link: function($scope) {
      alert('widget-dir');
    }
  };

});
myApp.directive('filterDir', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'filterController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<span>{{vm.test}}</span>",
    link: function($scope) {

      alert('filter-dir');
    }
  };
});
myApp.directive('iconDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope) {
      alert('icon-dir');
    }
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, [`controllerAs` was introduced in AngularJS **v1.2**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b3777f275c6bd2bd4a88963fd03828eb7cf3aca8) but in your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12208/) you are using **v1.0.1**. That is why `controllerAs` is not working for widget and filter directives.

Comment: Thanks,I tried all but didn't  check version.
It is working after upgrading